# Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

Tags: scripts, ubuntu-mate

When this is run,

```
#!/bin/bash 
#
# located in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/
# Created 4/2/19
exec 2> /tmp/systemd_suspend_test_err.txt
if [ "${1}" = "pre" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want before suspend here
  echo "we are suspending $(date)." > /home/andy/Downloads/message.txt
elif [ "${1}" = "post" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want after resume here
   echo "and we are back from being suspended $(date)" >> /home/andy/Downloads/message.txt
  #sleep 10
  #notify-send "Computer is returning from suspend." -t 2000
   gxmessage does NOT work and neither does inotify-send
  /usr/bin/gxmessage -fg red -font  'sans 30' -timeout 3  'Back from being suspended.'
fi
```

I get this in /tmp/systemd_suspend_test_err.txt.

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
gxmessage: unable to initialize GTK
```

Answer (score 0):

Before suspending, you can write xhost + which will allow clients to connect from any host (not recommended in production env - security concerns). Then, suspend and resume, the box with the red text appears.

```
# gxmessage works IF xhost + is run first.
  gxmessage -timeout 5 -fg red -display :0 'Back from being suspended.'
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to provide more info on how this solve the problem? Also the question could greatly be improved to be useful for other people.

Comment: Done. @Pablo Bianchi